# Unauthorized , android push notification

Tags: android, api, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, sha1

I follow  [this](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html) guide from google, to set up push notification service for android(GCM). But it is actually a bit wrong, because there is no **Register app** button, I think it was replaced with **credentials** in slide bar, then I press **create new key** button, chose **Android** then find in eclipse **SHA1 key** (I try with console, in /home/.android/debug.keystore, there was strange thing, it asks for some password I just press enter), and I add ';com.google.android.gcm.demo.app' - my application package in manifest(it is actually working example from http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) It works nice, when I enter my SENDER ID(project number from from google cloud console).

**Now I am going to write backend for this:**

1. I perform request and get 'Unauthorized' status code on my server(I suggest to skip details, it is actually doesn't matter).
2. Then I try to curl it, as it was written at google troubleshooting guide here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error. 
   I got the response with html tags, unauthorized 401.

How should I fix this issue?

**Note:** I suppose I generate key wrong way because of this mismatch in guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find solution I should open credentials in slide bar -> create new key - SERVER(instead of Android) then don't write any IP, it is enough for development purpose. Then this api key will be valid from server.

```
 api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

 curl --header "Authorization: key=$api_key" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

**response:**

```
{"multicast_id":6782339717028231855,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Then just enter valid registration ID, as written here:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error

It would be nice to change android guide here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html becouse it is not up to date.

Answer (score 2):

APIs & auth -> Credentials -> Create New Key -> Server Key -> Create(don't input IP)

Use Api Key in "Key for server applications"